# How to store a multi-lingual "dictionnary" in a NoSQL database?

Tags: schema, nosql

I hope this is the good Stack to ask this question, pardon me if it's not.

I need to categorize images and need manipulate a lot of words. I'll explain what's bugging me first and then there is a example document below.

For this, I need to store words in multiple languages in a database with their definition, type of word, emotion, etc.

For regular noun, like the month 'september', it is quite easy. But some words are more complicated, like 'shelter'.

Since `shelter` is a noun and can be a verb `to shelter` but are related and in french it becomes the noun `abri` and the verb `abriter`.

Some french words doesn't make any sense in english, like the verb `vouvoyer`, sometimes there will be a noun or a verb only in french or only in english.

My current object looks like this:

```
  {
    word: 'shelter', // act like a key
    type: ['noun', 'verb'],
    tags: ['structure', 'protection'],
    polarity: 'neutral',

    noun: {
      word: 'a shelter',
      definitions: []
    },
    verb: {
      word: 'to shelter',
      definitions: []
    },

    i18n: {
      // Languages
      fr: {
        type: ['noun', 'verb'],
        verb: {
          word: 'abriter',
          definitions: []
        },
        noun: {
          word: 'abri',
          mf: 'm',
          definitions: []
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The first issue here is in case of a word that only "exists" in french, I don't know where to put it.
I also think there is a lot of redundant information in this document.

I need to be able to query words by it's type, by it's tags and by language.

Before suggesting what would be the obvious easy (but complicated) solution: RDBMS, I want to use a high-availability database, probably MongoDB (since Cassandra would require me to have multiple dataset of the same data with different keys)

So, how can I store such information properly?

(Thanks!)

Comment: I think this is a great question and well worth the mental breakdown I'm sure you're having *(I've been there trust me)* But this seems as a crossover beteween database schema and scraping sentence structure. Just my 2 cents, you may want to look into sentence tokenizing / scraping. Might I suggest [TextBlob](http://rwet.decontextualize.com/book/textblob/)

Comment: Thanks @Jaba hahaha I'm looking right now at TextBlob. :)